# OutOfMemoryError in Fragment.onCreateView

Tags: android, out-of-memory

My android application runs fine on some devices but crashes on others. On my developer console, it shows OutOfMemoryError in ChaptersFragment.onCreateView. I have given the code below. I am a newbie and this is my first android application. Is there a solution to this or am I doing something wrong?

```
public class ChaptersFragment extends Fragment {
private CardView c1,c2,c3,c4,c5,c6,c7,c8,c9;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable 
ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_chapters, container, false);
    c1 = (CardView) myView.findViewById(R.id.chapter1);
    c2 = (CardView) myView.findViewById(R.id.chapter2);
    c3 = (CardView) myView.findViewById(R.id.chapter3);
    c4 = (CardView) myView.findViewById(R.id.chapter4);
    c5 = (CardView) myView.findViewById(R.id.chapter5);
    c6 = (CardView) myView.findViewById(R.id.chapter6);
    c7 = (CardView) myView.findViewById(R.id.chapter7);
    c8 = (CardView) myView.findViewById(R.id.chapter8);
    c9 = (CardView) myView.findViewById(R.id.chapter9);


    c1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Chap1.class);
            in.putExtra("some", "Introduction to Stock Markets");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    c2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Chap2.class);
            in.putExtra("some", "Technical Analysis");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    c3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Chap3.class);
            in.putExtra("some", "Fundamental Analysis");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    c4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Chap4.class);
            in.putExtra("some", "Futures Trading");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    c5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Chap5.class);
            in.putExtra("some", "Options Theory for Professional Trading");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    c6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Chap6.class);
            in.putExtra("some", "Options Strategies");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    c7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Chap7.class);
            in.putExtra("some", "Markets and Taxation");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    c8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Chap8.class);
            in.putExtra("some", "Currency and Commodity Futures");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    c9.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent in = new Intent(getActivity(), Chap9.class);
            in.putExtra("some", "Risk Management & Trading Psychology");
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    return myView;
 }
}
```

Comment: Is there some hi-resolution image drawable placed in your layout file? a background or something? Low memory devices will not be able to load and render hi res images.

Comment: There are some drawables placed in the layout file. But the total size of the drawables is 1.02 MB and the maximum resolution of the drawable is 700 x 700 pixels.

Comment: Here is the link to the project on github [link](https://github.com/ajithpoison/zerodha)

Answer (score 1):

When you set an Image on your layout, the rendered will try to scale it to desired size and try to accommodate it on your screen, it will consume some amount of memory during this process. Depending the memory available on your device it will easily  reach the maximum available memory (percent) per application Android OS computed.

700px may not seem a lot but if you have 9 images loaded in your layout and some must be resized to lower resolution by the system to fit your screen, the sum of necessary memory used to process this images will result in out-of-memory error.

Thats why you have to create multiple drawable folders containing different image sizes for each target device resolutions in your application. Don't have to be accurate, but you must manually resize your images close to desired size on the screen to avoid memory consumption during rendering process.

http://www.androiddocs.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html